# Change squid acl dstdomains without restarting

Tags: acl, squid

I have an *squid* server. I want to define an acl for *acceptable domains* while that domains are in *external file*.

this is the portion of **squid.conf**:

```
acl ourusers src x.x.x.x
acl goodsites dstdomain "/etc/squid3/acceptable_sites"
http_access allow goodsites ourusers
```

Now I want to change the content of */etc/squid3/acceptable_sites* **without** restarting (or reloading) the squid service.

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Please use "squid -k reconfigure"

Shahnawaz

Answer (score 0):

You must use squid -k reconfigure so it can "destroy" and rebuild the new rules you changed it. so it's impossible.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).